# Why don't menus in Nautilus or the desktop have shadows behind them?

Tags: 10.04, gnome, compiz, nautilus, nautilus-elementary

Menus in the file manager and desktop, both controlled by Nautilus, don't have shadows behind them when other GTK menus do? I'm running the proprietary nVidia drivers with Compiz, by the way.

Comment: Are you using nautilus elementary?

Comment: @DoR: Yes, I didn't think about that. I just checked on a computer that doesn't use nautilus-elementary and it didn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with the RGBA window transparency support in Nautilus Elementary.
The solution is to disable it:

1. *Edit ➜ Preferences ➜ Tweaks ➜ Uncheck 'Enable rgba transparency'*

   [image]
2. Restart Nautilus:

   ```
    killall nautilus
   ```